# how to query SQL for unique values for same record over the years

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the number of unique values for one record over time.  More specific, I have a table of facilities that has a name field, but most of the facilities have changed names over the years.  I want to find the unique names for each facility.  I am having trouble getting all of these values returned in one query.  Below is the query I created, but the problem is that it gives me the name of the facility for each year.  I only want when the name changed.

```
Select Distinct HAE.Name
            ,HAE.UniqueId
            ,S.Year
FROM HAEntity HAE
        INNER JOIN Survey S ON HAE.SurveyId=S.SurveyId
GROUP BY UniqueId, Name, Year
ORDER BY UniqueId, Name, Year
```

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Name                                         UniqueId Year

Hillsdale Community Health Center 46152 2013

Hillsdale Community Health Center 46152 2014

Hillsdale Hospital                         46152 2015
Hillsdale Hospital                         46152 2016

Comment: Thanks, I think SqlZim has already solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `Year` from your `group by` and get the `min()` `year` for each `Name` and `UniqueId`.

```
Select Distinct HAE.Name
            ,HAE.UniqueId
            ,min(S.Year) as Year
FROM HAEntity HAE
        INNER JOIN Survey S ON HAE.SurveyId=S.SurveyId
/* where facilities have had at least 1 name change */
where exists (
  select 1
    from HAEntity i
    where i.UniqueId = hae.UniqueId
    and i.Name<>hae.Name
    )
GROUP BY UniqueId, Name
ORDER BY UniqueId, Name, Year
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, if I only want facilities where the name changed is it possible to exclude facilities where the name has remained the same?

Comment: @DCity35 I have updated the answer to include a `where exists()` clause to check if the `UniqueId` has another `Name` in the `HAEntity` table. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you very much @SqlZim I appreciate all of your help, that is what I was trying to do!